# refresh Tkinter window in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, refresh

I made a simple "game 9" which works fine in pure Python. Now I want to do the same in Tkinter window.
I'm trying to refresh a Tkinter window through a key press - when I press the number (1-8) I set my matrix to different numbers and I want to refresh the window. Unfortunatelly I don't know how to do it well. I used window.update() and window.destroy() but this solution is bad. Can you please help how to refresh my Tkinter window without using window.destroy() ?
I'm new in Tkinter and also in Python :)

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep
import keyboard


x,px,py,px2,py2 = 0,0,0,0,0
matrix = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

# generate 9 unique numbers (0 to 8) and insert them into matrix 
z = random.sample(range(0,9),9)

matrix[0] = [(z[0]), (z[1]), (z[2])]
matrix[1] = [(z[3]), (z[4]), (z[5])]   
matrix[2] = [(z[6]), (z[7]), (z[8])]

def printmatrix():

    label1 = tk.Label(text = matrix[0])
    label1.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
    label2 = tk.Label(text = matrix[1])
    label2.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
    label3 = tk.Label(text = matrix[2])
    label3.grid(column = 1, row = 3)




# check win
def check_win():
    if matrix[0] == [1,2,3] and matrix[1] == [4,5,6] and matrix[2] == [7,8,0]:
        label4 = tk.Label(text = "you won !!!")
        label4.grid(column = 0, row = 6)
        window.update()
        sleep (5)
        exit ()


while __name__ == '__main__':
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("GAME 9")
    window.geometry("300x300")

    printmatrix()
    window.update()  


    check_win()

    # read key 1-8

    if keyboard.read_key() == "1":
        x = 1
    if keyboard.read_key() == "2":
        x = 2
    if keyboard.read_key() == "3":
        x = 3
    if keyboard.read_key() == "4":
        x = 4
    if keyboard.read_key() == "5":
        x = 5
    if keyboard.read_key() == "6":
        x = 6
    if keyboard.read_key() == "7":
        x = 7
    if keyboard.read_key() == "8":
        x = 8



# check position of "0"
    for pozx,j in enumerate(matrix):
        for pozy,l in enumerate(j):
            if l==0:
                px = int(pozx)
                py = int(pozy)


# check position of moved number
    for pozx2,j in enumerate(matrix):
        for pozy2,l in enumerate(j):
            if l==x:
                px2 = int(pozx2)
                py2 = int(pozy2)


# check if the moved number is on the right place  (if we can use it)
    if  (px == px2 or py == py2) and ((py+1 or py-1 == py2) or (px+1 or px-1 == px2)):
        if (px == 0 and px2 == 1) or (px == 1 and px2 == 2) or (px == 1 and px2 == 0) or (px == 2 and px2 == 1) or (py == 0 and py2 == 1) or (py == 1 and py2 == 2) or (py == 1 and py2 == 0) or (py == 2 and py2 == 1):


            matrix[px2][py2] = 0
            matrix[px][py] = x
            printmatrix()


        else:
            label5 = tk.Label(text = "wrong move, try again")
            label5.grid(column = 0, row = 5)
            window.update()
            sleep(2)
            printmatrix()


    else:
        label6 = tk.Label(text = "wrong move, try again")
        label6.grid(column = 0, row = 4)
        window.update()
        sleep(2)
        printmatrix()


    window.destroy()  
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: don't use module `keyboard` but `tkinter` methods to bind function to pressed key - `root.bind("1", function_name)` and inside this function set variable. You will have to learn how all GUI frameworks work and rewrite it.

Comment: create all labels at start and later only change text in labels. Don't create again and again Labels in the same place because previous labes are still in window and use memory.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it to the end but it uses methods which are used in most GUIs.

It bind/assign functions to keys so the run `move(number)` and it move number.

It creates labels at start and later only change text in labes.

It doesn't need any `update` because it updates it automatically.

BTW: like in matrix used in math I use `[row][column]` which means `[y][x]`, not `[x][y]`

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
import time

# generate 9 unique numbers (0 to 8) and insert them into matrix 
z = random.sample(range(0,9),9)

matrix = [
    [(z[0]), (z[1]), (z[2])],
    [(z[3]), (z[4]), (z[5])],
    [(z[6]), (z[7]), (z[8])],
]    
#print(matrix)

def update_labels():
    for row_matrix, row_labels in zip(matrix, labels):
        for item, label in zip(row_matrix, row_labels): 
            label["text"] = item


def move(number):
    #print(number)

    # find position of "0" and moved number
    for y, row in enumerate(matrix):
        for x, cell in enumerate(row):
            if cell == 0:
                zero_x = x
                zero_y = y
            elif cell == number:
                number_x = x
                number_y = y

    # check if the moved number is on the right place  (if we can use it)
    diff_x = abs(zero_x - number_x)
    diff_y = abs(zero_y - number_y)
    if (diff_x == 0 and diff_y == 1) or (diff_x == 1 and diff_y == 0):
            matrix[number_y][number_x] = 0
            matrix[zero_y][zero_x] = number
    else:
        message_label['text'] = "wrong move, try again"

    update_labels()
    check_win()

def check_win():
    if matrix == [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,0]]:
        message_label['text'] = "you won !!!"
        time.sleep(5)
        exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("GAME 9")
    window.geometry("300x300")

    # create labels
    labels = []
    for y in range(1, 4):
        row = []
        for x in range(1, 4): 
            label = tk.Label(window)
            label.grid(column=x, row=y)
            row.append(label)
        labels.append(row)

    # label for messages        
    message_label = tk.Label(window)
    message_label.grid(column=0, row=4, columnspan=5)

    # fill labels at start
    update_labels()

    # bind keys to function
    for i in range(1, 10):
        window.bind(str(i), lambda event, x=i:move(x))

    # start program and show window
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks for response, some things are more clear to me now. And I can see your code is on another level (compared to mine). I have to learn much :)